# beforeEach not called via Karma/ Jasmine in an angularjs/ requirejs scenario

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, requirejs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Running my unit tests locally works fine but on the build server the most stupid thing happens: Sometimes they pass, sometimes they don't. The main code:

```
define(['angmock', 'someMore'], function () {
    describe('myController', function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
        console.log("Entry - Initializing modules...");
        module('module1');
        module('module2');
        console.log("Exit - Initializing modules...");
    });

    var scope, controller;
    beforeEach(inject(function ($rootScope, $controller) {
        console.log("Entry - Creating scope...");

        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('myController', {
            $scope: scope
        });

        console.log("Exit - Creating scope...");
    }));

    it('should test something', function () {
        console.log("Entry - Test A");
        scope.myImportantAssignment = variableName;
        ...
        console.log("Exit - Test A");
    });
...
```

In the build server log I can sometimes read:

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating
>   'scope.myImportantAssignment = variableName')

And on the console I can read:

- LOG: 'Entry - Initializing modules...'
- LOG: 'Exit - Initializing modules...'
- LOG: 'Entry - Test A'

That could show that the second beforeEach is not called at all and thus the scope is not initialized. But why? In my easy mind the processing should work like:

- beforeEach 1
- beforeEach 2
- it

But that does not seem to be the case. Is there probably some problems with async? Any little hint is greatly appreciated as I can not use the tests at all if they are sometimes failing...

Comment: It is hard to estimate the precedence because closing brackets and indentations aren't matched! Considering that both `beforeEach` and `it` are hosted by the same `describe('myController',...)` block, there are no race conditions that could explain the problem, the blocks are sync and always run in sequence. This may happen if the app silently fails to be bootstrapped and throws on `inject` (there should be errors in the console, but PhantomJS is known for swallowing errors).

Comment: estus, thanks for your feedback. The hosting is ok but it could have to do something with the injection. I can now reproduce the error locally if I remove a requirejs define in the first line. In my case it is 'kendo/kendo.angular.min'. But I don't understand why this could cause an injection error nor how to fix it. Any ideas? I'll post the solution here if I will ever find one...

Comment: The cause can be literally anything that is involved in bootstrapping process. You can change Karma launcher to Chrome and see if it improves error output. Moving `inject` from `beforeEach` to `it` can also help. Why is Kendo there in the first place? In unit tests the app units are tested, everything else should be mocked, having extra dependencies adds more moving parts to the specs (and it doesn't help, as you can see).

Comment: It seems that the dependency is sometimes not found. And of course you are right about questioning the existance of libraries like kendo. I'll have a deeper look into that and if I find some deeper insights I'll update your answer (as you helped me in tracking things down I would love to accept an answer from you - if you want to post one! :))

Comment: Sure, you are welcome.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are no race conditions that could explain the problem, the blocks are sync and always run in sequence. This may happen if the app silently fails to be bootstrapped and throws on `inject`.

There should be errors in the console, but PhantomJS is known for swallowing errors, changing Karma launcher to Chrome may improve error output.

Moving `inject` from `beforeEach` to `it` can also help to locate the problem, it makes the spec to fail not on failed expectation but on the error that makes this expectation to fail.

In unit tests the app units are tested, everything else should be mocked, having extra dependencies (Angular wrapper for Kendo UI) adds more moving parts to the specs.